# iterate over nested arrays and provide access to each index

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I am going through a lesson on Javascript Arrays where we have to understand certain what is under the hood of underscoreJS methods. I need to write a function for the _.each method which will allow me to iterate over a single array and return a modified nested array that includes the index for each value.
For example:

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

after the method each is called on myArray the new array should look like:

```
myArray = [ [ 'a', 0 ], [ 'b', 1 ], [ 'c', 2 ] ];
```

I have been searching on google for a day and have not found anything specific to this task. Stuck and need some help! Thank you.

Comment: You can't solve that with `each`. Use `map` instead.

Comment: She's learning `each`. `map` is better, but that's next.

Answer (score 2):

`_.each` iterates over your array and has the following signature

`function(value, index, array)`

So lets see how it could be done ...

```
var result = [];
_.each(myArray, function(value, index, array){
  result.push([value, index]); // <= does the work
}
```

This is not the ideal way (you should use `map`) but does illustrate how the each works.

Good luck

Comment: This is not pure JavaScript you are using, but rather lodash or underscore, which you don't even mention. I prefer the other answers that use plain JavaScript solutions, although they should mention that these are not available in each browser.

Comment: To be clear. This explains how to do it with the `each` method as asked. Not ideal but the answer to the question. Down vote ... really?

Comment: From the question it's obvious lodash/underscore is being used!

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. I changed it to an upvote

Comment: No problem. I remember my time grinding thru' the underscore code. It's a great way to learn

Comment: thanks for the insight. yes i realize this is not the best way to do it but my program wants us to learn what is under the hood of the underscore code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below by using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function,

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var result = myArray.reduce(function(a,b,i){ 
 return (a.push([b,i]), a)
},[]);
console.log(result); // [['a',0],['b',1],['c',2]];
```

Or as @bergi said you can do it with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) also,

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var result = myArray.map(function(itm,i){ 
 return [itm,i];
});
console.log(result); // [['a',0],['b',1],['c',2]];
```

Comment: this presupposes that aileen knows what .reduce does.. which is more advanced than foreach.

Comment: maybe explain or link to those functions in mozilla docs? While I fully approve this answer, a lot of JavaScript programmers are not familiar with the functional programming paradigm

Comment: @froginvasion Sorry, Its 3 am here in India. I just slept on my keyboard.  I have added links to the official docs. :)

Comment: Nothing good ever happens after 1 AM ;). Hehe, thanks for adding :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```js
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    result = myArray.map(function (a, i) {
        return [a, i];
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're learning `_.each` method, you can do it like this

```js
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

_.each(myArray, function (e, i) {
    myArray[i] = [e, i];
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

But for your case better to use `_.map` function